# As a security engineer would you be okay recommending macapps.link?

Tags: macos, threat-modeling

I really like macapps.link as it helps me to quickly install a bunch of software after a fresh install. However, it doesn't have the transparency such Windows alternatives, like ninite or winget have.

Answer (score 3):

From a short view this site lets you select applications and then asks you to install these with

```
curl -s https://api.macapps.link/app-specific-part | sh
```

This means it is sending some shell instructions from the site to your shell which get blindly executed there.

Right now these commands are a shell script which checks if you have these apps already installed in the current version and if not seems to download and install the disk images from the original source (checked with Chrome and Firefox).

But, it could be anything else. If somebody compromises the site they could make your system execute arbitrary commands. This might not be that obvious immediately since it might still install the intended apps but then also do something malicious but hidden in addition. Or it might installed a maliciously modified versions of these apps. Or the malicious behavior might be installed but only be activated later once enough users are infected.

This could also be done only for some selected users (randomly selected, by IP address, by time, by app ...), so that it does not get obvious that bad things happen. And of course, this could not only be done if the site is compromised but the owners of the site could do this too. I'm not saying the they do, but there is no way to be sure.

Or in other words: From the perspective of an attacker it would be an attractive and cheap way to setup such a site in order to infect some users. There is not much cost involved (the site only serves the script, not the actual software images) and one can reach lots of potential gullible victims with such a slick site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by *professional context* (i.e. where do you work). Risk assessment is your friend here.

This site seems legit, the script that you are asked to execute also seems legit. From the looks of it, the owner of the site needed something practical to assist him to install software in his fresh installs and converted it to a site so that others may benefit from his effort (and make donations).

Now, if you work somewhere where you need to be extra careful about everything (i.e. government agencies, financial institutions, defense industry etc) then you need to be skeptical of programs/scripts that you are asked to execute in your computer; executing programs from untrusted<sup>1</sup> suppliers should not be allowed. As such, even *suggesting* to others to use such a site, may not be appropriate (if not against some policy).

On the other hand, if you work in a low risk, low impact environment (e.g. a grocery store, where your computer stores an inventory of items that you have in your low-capacity warehouse), then I guess it's ok to allow some security rules to be relaxed (precautions may *still* be required, of course, such as the existence of a backup and restoration plan).

---

<sup>1</sup> untrusted can be either a supplier that you don't know if he's legit (e.g. a random person on the internet setting up a site, serving software) or a legit one, but for whom you don't know if he's taken security seriously. In principle, untrusted means *not approved by the people in charge*